# Why would `read -s` behaves differently than `read` if killed with `ctrl-c`?

Tags: bash, sudo, read, exec

Consider this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "hi there $(whoami)"

[ "`whoami`" = "root" ] || {
  exec sudo -u root "$0" "$@"
  echo "this is never called"
}

read -s -p "enter stuff: " stuff
echo "answer: $stuff"
```

If I run it as user `lars` and enter `woohoo`, then I get the following output:

```
hi there lars
hi there root
enter stuff:
answer: woohoo
```

However, if I `ctrl-c` while the script is waiting for my `read` input, then I get into a weird state. The console seems to be stuck in silent mode. The problem does not occur if I omit the `-s` (= Silent mode) option.

Do you have any idea what the exact problem is here? How can I make the script behave properly if someone presses `ctrl-c` during the input.

I am running bash 4.3.30.

Comment: Can not reproduce.

Comment: @Isaac I just replicated the behavior on a Amazon ECS machine with Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS (trusty) and BASH 4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu).

On what environment did you test?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this is a [bug in Bash 4.3 that was fixed in Bash 4.4](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/CHANGES):

> oo. Fixed a bug that caused bash to not clean up readline's state, including the terminal settings, if it received a fatal signal while in a readline() call (including `read -e' and `read -s').

I worked around the problem with a trap that restores the terminal settings:

```
    [ "`whoami`" = "root" ] || {
      exec sudo -u root "$0" "$@"
    }

    function finish {
      stty echo echok
    }
    trap finish EXIT
    read -s -p "enter stuff: " stuff
    echo "answer: $stuff"
```