# Reset terminal after interrupting `read -r -s`

Tags: bash, read

If I run

```
read -r -s INPUT
```

And then interrupt it with Ctrl-C, then the terminal stays in a state where all the input characters are not shown.

How can I restore the terminal after such an incident?

Comment: Interestingly, I cannot duplicate this with either version 4.3 or version 4.4 of the Bourne Again shell.

Comment: Yeah, I am using bash 3.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command used to reset the terminal is aptly named:

```
reset
```

However, this would likely clear the terminal as well.

You may also try

```
stty echo
```

which would turn on echoing of what you type, or

```
stty sane
```

which should get your terminal back into a sane state.

If the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key does not seem to work, you may use <kbd>Ctrl+J</kbd> instead.

Comment: In some cases it may be necessary to use `<CTRL-J>reset<CTRL-J>` instead of pressing the `<Enter>` or `<Return>` key as usual. `<CTRL-J>stty sane<CTRL-J>` might also be used if the terminal is in some strange state.

Comment: `stty echo` worked for me. I used `trap 'stty echo && exit 1' SIGINT`

Comment: It's unlikely to be a strange state, Bodo, or anything approaching needing even `stty sane` let alone `reset` ([which is overkill](https://superuser.com/a/1259560/38062)).  The action of the `-s` option to `read` is both simple and documented.

Comment: @Bodo not in this case -- bash's readline will NOT turn off `icrnl`, and if some hobgoblin has taken over your tty, he may just as well do a `stty -icrnl inlcr` (and the advice from the end of the answer is useless). But it's quite curious how the OP got there -- bash's readline *should* reset the term itself upon SIGINT and turn echo back on.

Comment: [And it does](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/463601/5132).